# CORS + Cordova : issues with : Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, cors

I have been searching hours on this issue, but I still can't find any solution to this.

I am developping an App cordova (basicely HTML / JS)
So : the app runs on mobile from the navigator, and I have trouble making an ajax request to an API : https://developer.riotgames.com/
But let's say that I just want to get the google page.

How on earth do I do that, is this even possible ?
Here is a simple exemple :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://google.com",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response){
        alert("!!!");
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert("...");
    }
});
```

I am getting the same error again and again :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://google.com/. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

The origin 'null' is because I run the code from : `file:///D:/Projets/LoL/www/index.html` and I read that the navigator is blocking, but it doesn't work as well if I disable the security with `--disable-web-security`
And of course, I don't have access to the server I want to join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) . I'd suggest doing some reading on JSONP but in general if you can't modify the server, there's no good way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 31):

You need the Cordova whitelist plugin: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/.

Have this in config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

And have the Content-Security-Policy meta in index.html. Something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I run as browser.
I still have:

 "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:7788/testAction. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: If you deploy to a handset you may have better results. I read (unfortunately I cannot recall where) that the CORS responses are slightly different when run from app or browser.  I created a test app with CORS enabled in my meta tags and it only worked when I deployed it to my phone - not from my desktop.

Comment: Throws me like 500 errors of Refused Content Security Policy directive

Comment: I had to complement this tips with the information found in this site: https://content-security-policy.com... and all is working now.

Comment: Adding <allow-navigation href="*"/> to config.xml fixed it for me. Adding the meta tag to index.html threw me some exotic error tho

Comment: @kristofvdj88 maybe try an easy example first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy

Comment: That is not secure at all. Even Cordova documentation recommends not to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If the Cordova Whitelist plugin doesn't work out for you, you can use the Cordova advanced Http plugin to make calls to external servers.

Install using:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Link to plugin:
https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http?ref=hackernoon.com

Extra info:
https://hackernoon.com/a-practical-solution-for-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-issues-in-ionic-3-and-cordova-2112fc282664

Answer (score 0):

I have added following in nodejs server which solves my issue;

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

This may be helpful if you are using nodejs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just experienced the issue starting Aug 1 2019. This [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error..(using cordova)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937905/access-control-allow-origin-error-using-cordova/57489240#57489240) might be related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do such thing

You just try to change the permission

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my similar scenario, was getting the error:
"access-control-allow-origin cannot contain more than one origin"

Eventually I found that although I had set my .net core API to allow all sources like so:

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
...

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
...
```

I had then left an old CORS command in the web.config file in the website root of the API:

```js
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://localhost:444" />
     </customHeaders>
```

I commented out the customHeaders section and it worked.

Mission accomplished!