# How can I use html with ajax call in cordova in ios build?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, cordova, cordova-ios

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(
            "Authorization",
            "Basic " + btoa("test" + ":" + "test@password")
          );
        },
    url : pathUrl+"login",
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
        'email' : email,
        'password' : password
    },
    success : function(responses) {
        response = JSON.parse(responses);
        if(response.success == true) {
            localStorage.setItem('user', response.user_.id);
            localStorage.setItem('loginEmail', response.user_.email);
            window.location.href = 'home.html';
            localStorage.setItem("ID", "uni_id");
        }
        else {
            alert(response.message);
        }

    }
});
```

It's working fine in android device but its not working in ios device.
It's retunes xmlhttprequest cannot load due to access control checks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [cordova cannot load due to access control checks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398805/2181514)

Comment: Can you include the *exact* message?

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your response. If I send request with beforesend then it's return with preflight error. So is their any alternative method of breforesend in ajax call?

Comment: Can you include the *exact* message?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s-gjIu_9OK0W8veQexBGtWJfUzsgtBZ6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr